# to make a slide with navigation arrow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble creating a navigation control to a slide. 
the problem is the arrow to return to previous.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/joseferreira/ka47jo7z/10/

```
var gridwidth = $("#special").width();
        var itens = $("#special .grid-special").length;
        var b = 0;

        $(".hidden-grid").css("width", gridwidth * itens);

        var animate = function () {
            $(".hidden-grid").stop().animate({
                marginLeft: -b * gridwidth
            }, {
                duration: 1000,
                specialEasing: {
                    marginLeft: "linear",
                }
            });
        }

        $(".next, .prev").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
                b++;
                console.log(b);
                if (b < itens) {
                    animate();
                } else {
                    alert('end');
                }
            } else {
                b--;
                console.log(b);
                if (b >= 0) {
                    animate();
                } else {
                    alert('begin');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Works fine for me! What is the problem exactly?

Comment: an alert is shown when previous button is clicked..what is that you want???

Comment: @Lal maybe the problem is that after `alert` you have to click to "next" button twice before slide is changed.

Comment: So if problem is in it, here is [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/ka47jo7z/11/), which fixes this bug.

Comment: I too has fixed that bug.. @Regent ..check my answer please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/ka47jo7z/13/)

Ive edited the JS such that if value of b becomes negative ,i incremented b after showing the alert and for the next button i've decremented b after showing the alert..Thus the problem is solved for both the buttons.

**JS**

```
$(".next, .prev").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
                b++;
                console.log(b);
                if (b < itens) {
                    animate();
                } else {
                    alert('chegou no fim');
                    b--;
                }
            } else {
                b--;
                console.log(b);

                if (b >= 0) {
                    animate();
                }else{

                    alert('voltou para o inicio');
                    b++;

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had fixed same kind of bug for `next` button. So it will be good if you fix second bug too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do even better using 2dtransform (`jquery.transform2d.js`) plugin. I have created a working example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/96czftL1/1/).

I have also animated the navigation arrows using CSS transitions.

To better understand CSS Transforms Matrix, visit this [page](http://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/).

Comment: It works for me. Does the arrow maximize when you hover over it?

Comment: It's probably because I have added the transform2d plugin from github's raw file. I'll change it.